# The UICollectoinViewCell has no member of present (in order to present another view )?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uicollectionviewcell, uistoryboardsegue

I have created a class for the custom cell that I use for a collection view in my app . In this cell I have a button that I'd like to lead to another storyboard from the current one . So I tried to use present as follow :

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let cr = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "test")
            self.present(cr, animated: true)
```

but there is a problem with sender which in this case is self. The error says UICollectionViewCell has no member of present which make sense. But then how can I achive my goal as I may need to use the same concept for segus in order to transfer information from one storyboard to another ?

Comment: Actually you cant call self.present from CustomCell, you need to call and add this method in the Controller in which UICollectionView exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your problem can fixed in that way

In your custom `CollectionViewCell` add `Button` as `IBOutlet` i.e

```
class CustomCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var btnDemo: UIButton!
    //Otherstuff
}
```

And in the `ViewController` that has the `CollectionView` add `IBAction` from the that `UIButton` on the CustomCell and in the `CellForRowAtIndexPath` you need to add tag to that button in order to identify which button you clicked i.e

```
class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    @IBAction func btnButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) 
    {         
        let currentBtn = sender as UIButton
    } 
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
         cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> 
         UICollectionViewCell 
    {
       //Initialize Cell and other necessary stuff
       currentCell.btnDemo.tag = indexPath.row
    }
```